# Laravel get data from relationship and show in view

Tags: php, laravel, properties, relationship

simply this code is my get data solution, this models are relationships and my result is true but i can't get data from relationship and show that on view, for example;

```php
$data = UserAccountNumber::with(['currency_type'])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(50);
```

this code return below result:

```php
LengthAwarePaginator {#585 ▼
  #total: 2
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#601 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => UserAccountNumber {#588 ▶}
      1 => UserAccountNumber {#589 ▼
        #table: "user_account_numbers"
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        #connection: null
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #perPage: 15
        +incrementing: true
        +timestamps: true
        #attributes: array:9 [▼
          "id" => 2
          "user_id" => 17
          "account_number" => "24234234"
          "card_number" => "242423423"
          "sheba" => "asdasdad"
          "currency_type" => 5
          "status" => 0
          "created_at" => "2016-05-13 10:55:00"
          "updated_at" => "2016-05-13 10:55:00"
        ]
        #original: array:9 [▶]
        #relations: array:1 [▼
          "currency_type" => CurrencyType {#603 ▼
            #table: "currency_type"
            #fillable: array:3 [▶]
            #dates: array:1 [▶]
            #connection: null
            #primaryKey: "id"
            #perPage: 15
            +incrementing: true
            +timestamps: true
            #attributes: array:7 [▼
              "id" => 5
              "user_id" => 1
              "currency_type" => "EURO"
              "currency_symbol" => "EUR"
              "created_at" => "2016-04-17 12:07:47"
              "updated_at" => "2016-04-17 12:07:47"
              "deleted_at" => null
            ]
```

**View:**

in view i can get `UserAccountNumber` data, but i can not get `currency_type` and show that on view:

```php
<table class='table-style' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    @foreach ($data as $key=>$contents)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$contents->card_number}}</td>
            <td>{{$contents->card_number}}</td>
            <td>{{$contents->seba}}</td>
            <td>{{$contents->created_at}}</td>
            <td>
                {{$contents->currency_type->currency_type}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

i get error for `{{$contents->currency_type->currency_type}}` on view.

**Error:**

```php
Trying to get property of non-object
```

**POST UPDATED:**

```php
class UserAccountNumber extends Model
{
    protected $table   = 'user_account_numbers';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\User');
    }

    public function currency_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\CurrencyType', 'currency_type', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `UserAccountNumber` model please?

Comment: @codedge yes sir. post updated.

Comment: I still can't see any `class UserAccountNumber` model class..

Comment: @codedge thats end of my topic. i think my relation ship is not correct. please let me to paste code to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to improve is in your `UserAccountNumber` model. Your `currency_type` relation should be written like:

```php
public function currencyType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CurrencyType::class, 'currency_type', 'id');
}
```

Your call would then look like:

```php
// using the currencyType() method from above
$data = UserAccountNumber::with('currencyType') 
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(50);
```

You then can access the currency type in your with with:

```php
@foreach ($data as $key=>$contents)
    $contents->currencyType->currency_type
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems some of the `UserAccountNumber` do not have `currency_type` attached to it. Add something like this to your code:

```
@if (isset($contents->currency_type))
    {{ $contents->currency_type->currency_type }}
@endif
```

Or:

```
{{ $contents->currency_type->currency_type or 'There is not type' }}
```

Comment: `currency_type` is an relationship

Comment: But if there is a proper relation, i. e. one-to-many, one CurrencyType-to-many-UserAccountNumbers, there should always be a CurrencyType, right @Alexey?